# cannot resolve symbol ofPattern

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to use Java time to format a date in a particular way so that I can search for the date in a text file. I've imported java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter but when I enter the code

```
DateTimeFormatter formatDate = new DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

it displays the error "Cannot resolve symbol ofPattern". I can't see what I'm doing wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: There is no `ofPattern()` with zero arguments. There is however `ofPattern(String pattern)` and `ofPattern(String pattern, Locale locale)`

Comment: I suggest next time you run into a problem, first consult the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues in this snippet:

1. As Phil correctly pointed, there is no method `ofPattern` taking zero arguments. According javadoc you should use either [`ofPattern(String pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-), either [`ofPattern(String pattern, Locale locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-)
2. Both such methods are static, so you don't need object at all

Bringing all the things together

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd");
```

Hope it helps!